# Why did Ron yell "He beat you"?

Tags: harry-potter, books

In the book, when the Voldemort shows Harry's seemingly dead body, he is forced to put a silencing charm on the Hogwartians. Then Ron yells "He beat you" all of a sudden - breaking the silencing charm in the process.

What's the meaning of this statement? Why does Ron say it? Does he know that Harry isn't dead (which is highly unlikely?)

Comment: Ron knew that all the horcruxes were now destroyed, and Harry had a significant role.

Answer (score 8):

## Ron likely meant Harry’s past victories.

Directly before Ron’s yell, Voldemort tells the crowd of onlookers that Harry was and had always been nothing but a boy who relied on others’ sacrifice. Right after this statement is when Ron yells out to Voldemort “he beat you”.

> “You see?’ said Voldemort, and Harry felt him striding backwards and forwards right beside the place where he lay. ‘Harry Potter is dead! Do you understand now, deluded ones? He was nothing, ever, but a boy who relied on others to sacrifice themselves for him!’
>
> ‘He beat you!’ yelled Ron, and the charm broke, and the defenders of Hogwarts were shouting and screaming again until a second, more powerful bang extinguished their voices once more.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

Ron likely objected to the suggestion that his friend was nothing, and his yell of “he beat you” was likely his attempt of telling Voldemort that Harry was good enough to have beaten him before then. Ron likely did not know Harry was actually alive then, and had won again that day, but simply meant that Harry had won against Voldemort before.